# Remove item from array by click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

By clicking on an array element, I add it to the end of the new array

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell" v-for="item in posts" :key="item">
    <img :class="{active: item.isActive}" :src="item.url" alt width="293px" height="293px" @click="choosePost(item)" />
  </div>
</div>

    choosePost(item) {
    item.isActive = !item.isActive
    if (item.isActive == true) {
      this.selectedPosts.push(item)
    } else this.selectedPosts.splice(????, 1)
  console.log(this.selectedPosts)
},
```

I want to make it so, that when I click on an element again, it will be removed from the array. I tried using the splice method but I don’t understand how can I get the index of the selected item. Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indexes in an v-for loop look:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell" v-for="(item, index) in posts" :key="item">
    <img :class="{active: item.isActive}" :src="item.url" alt width="293px" height="293px" @click="choosePost(item, index)" />
  </div>
</div>

choosePost(item, index) {
    item.isActive = !item.isActive
    if (item.isActive == true) {
      item["posIndex"] = index;
      this.selectedPosts.push(item)
    } else {
      let pos = this.selectedPosts.map(function(e) { return e.posIndex; }).indexOf(index);
      this.selectedPosts.splice(pos, 1);
    }
  console.log(this.selectedPosts)
},
```

Comment: https://skr.sh/v1volChtKlu only works with the first element of the old array. I can not understand why

Comment: how does `item` looks like can you show me the strucutre=

Comment: https://skr.sh/v1vNoSKD5yD everything is fine with the first element. property "isActive" at next elements change to false, but that elements don't remove at the array

Comment: try this code out. you slice the wrong index. if you select for example the second item, your index will be 1. and that item is gonna be stored in `selectedPosts`. But when u try to slice it, you slice the item at index 1 but `selectedPosts` contain only 1 value so his index is 0 not 1. I have written an one-line code to get the correct index of that element

Comment: select the 3rd element and then un-select it. `pos` should be `0`

Answer (score 2):

You can get `index` in `v-for`:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell" v-for="(item, index) in posts" :key="item">
    <img
      :class="{ active: item.isActive }"
      :src="item.url"
      width="293px"
      height="293px"
      @click="choosePost(item, index)"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://skr.sh/v1volChtKlu only works with the first element of the old array. I can not understand why